# Laravel Unique keyword for particular Column

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

I'm using "unique" keyword for validating unique users for employee_id in controllers, in my database there is column called company_id , while adding new user they will be set us some company_id ,when i add new user for my company employee id will be unique for my company itself , if employee_id is 4 for another company and i'm adding 4 for my company it must accept , it will check only for that particular company only.

```
       $this->validate($request, 
       [
        'name'      => 'required',
        'emp_id' => 'required|unique:users', (Here how can i check for particular company)
        'email' => 'required|unique:users',
        'role'  => 'required',
       ]);
```

can anyone please help me ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the array syntax here and use a "custom" unique rule:

```
'emp_id' => [ "required",  Rule::unique('users')->where(function ($query) use ($request) {
   $query->where('emp_id', $request->emp_id)->where("company_id",$request->company_id); 
}) ]
```

Something like this anyway

Comment: I appreciate your ans, just want to know is it not same as I given `'emp_id' => 'required|unique:users,emp_id|unique:users,company_id',` ?

Comment: No, `required|unique:users,emp_id|unique:users,company_id` requires that `emp_id` is unique on both `emp_id` and `company_id` on users. That's unlikely to be desired because `company_id` and `emp_id` are not the same kind of identifier. This answer assumes there is a second request field `$request->company_id` which must also satisfy the unique condition (in practice the combination `emp_id,company_id` must be unique)

Answer (score 1):

If `emp_id` and `company_id` is in request

```
'emp_id' => 'required|unique:users,emp_id|unique:users,company_id',
```

Check in docs : https://laravel.com/docs/master/validation#rule-unique

I assume `emp_id` and `company_id` are present in `users` table and you are sending in request

Comment: how can i check this emp_id='4' is present in particular company_id='tech'   ..
            'emp_id' => 'required|unique:users,company_id,$company_id',

Comment: what you are sending `emp_id` or `company_id` and is present in which table `users` ?

Comment: i want to check emp_id for company_id. if emp_id='4' for company_id='tech' is already there in database and i can able to add emp_id='4' for company_id='technology' but i can't able to add emp_id='4' for company_id='tech' & also 'technology'.. did u understand ??

Comment: No still i'm getting same issue. :(

Comment: do you have both `emp_id` and `company_id` column in `users` table ?

Comment: yeah it is in same table .

Comment: do you get any error ? or just storing without getting error ? if yes share  ?

Comment: what if you provide `unique company id ` and `unique id of employee` ? I should be save in table ?

Comment: yeah it should store in same table

Comment: I means try with `unique company id ` and `unique employee id ` and let me know it is storing in table or not ?

Comment: $this->validate($request, [
            'name'      => 'required',
            'emp_id' => 'required|unique:users,emp_id|unique:users,company_id',
            'email' => 'required|unique:users',
            'role'  => 'required',
        ]); can you please give me exact solution using my code ?

Comment: Please try as @apokryfos given , I think he is right.

Comment: Sure.. :) Thank you for ur response for my question.